# Using Highchart Pie Chart from ORACLE Data

Tags: php, oracle, charts

I am using highcharts pir chart and i need to record 2 dimensional array of data into the javascript and the parameter accepts like this

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Weight',
            data: [
                ['DATA1',   DATA2], //Row 1
                ['DATA1',   DATA2], //Row 2 etc....
            ]
        }]
```

So im fetching everything thru oracle query that looks like this

```
$i = 0;
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($buildingOverviewParse)){
        $buildingName = $row['PROJECTNAME'];
        $percentagePerBuilding = $row['PERCENTAGE'];
        $i++;
    }

    $buildingVal[$i] = strval($buildingName);
    $percentageVal[$i] = doubleval($percentagePerBuilding);
```

and on the script,

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Weight',
            data: [ buildingValue, percentageValue
            ]
        }]
```

I havent had any luck on this, can somebody please help me ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Is your series data dynamic? if so are you returning in JSON format?

Comment: yes its dynamic depending on how many rows returned from the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken another page called *getGraphs.php* to get your data for charts.

In your highcharts

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',                    
        name: 'Weight',
        data: []
    }]
} 
$.getJSON("getGraphs.php", function(json) {
   if ( json.length != 0 )
    {
        options.series[0].data = json;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
    else
    {
       //Show some message that data is empty
    }

});
```

Then, In your `getGraphs.php`

```
$result = mysql_query("----Query----"); // Fetch data to display in your chart
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rows,$row);
}
print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: So i tried your code and it seems im having a problem in the class with has the highcharts, you can take a look here http://pastie.org/9943332

Comment: what issues you are facing?

Comment: you can take a look at here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492571/json-data-transfer-in-highcharts-doesnt-work

Comment: You MUST use JSON. Its the best practice for highcharts